# How to use filter to search when press a button

Tags: vue.js

Design:
[image]

I am going to make event for the buttons to filter different operas. I am not sure it should use filter() to search or other method? If I really need to use filter(), how can I set the condition? It is should not be written manually. It is not make sense to set filter(xx = yy) for each button. Is it similar to my handleActiveIndex? Store the value of the button and put it into filter() to search related operas?

Template:

```
<!-- Search filter -->
<div class="search-part">
  <div class="label-bar">
    <swiper
      :slidesPerView="5"
      :navigation="true"
      :modules="modules"
      class="mySwiper"
    >
      <!-- Loop labels -->
      <swiper-slide
        v-for="(label, index) in labels"
        :key="index"
        @click="handleActiveIndex(index)"
      >
        <button class="button-text">{{ label.type }}</button>
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>

    <!-- Sub label -->
    <div class="choice-list">
      <div
        class="choice"
        v-for="(choice, index) in labels[activeIndex].choice"
        :key="index"
      >
        {{ choice }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
setup() {
  /* Filter label */
  const labels = ref([
   {
     type: "Stage Pefromnace",
     choice: [
       "All",
       "Music",
       "Chinese Opera",
       "Dance",
       "Theatre",
       "Multi-Arts",
       "Pop Concerts",
     ],
   },
   {
     type: "Festivals",
     choice: [
       "All",
       "International Arts Carnival",
       "New Vision Arts Festival",
       "New Vision Arts Festival",
       "Chinese Opera Festival",
       "Hong Kong Pop Culture Festival",
       "Other Festivals / Series Events",
     ],
   },
   {
     type: "Family Entertainment",
     choice: ["All"],
   },
   // other btns ...
 ]);


/* Show Data */
const shows = ref([
  {
     image: "src/image/search-section/1.jpg",
     imgRes: "src/image/recommendation/responsive/rec1-r.jpg",
     name: "Chinese Opera Festival 2023: Opening Programme - Peking Opera Theatre of Beijing",
     date: "2023/06/16-18",
     location: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
     category: ["Music", "Family Entertainment"],
     free: "F",
     price: "",
     saleDate: "2023/06/1",
  },
  {
     image: "src/image/search-section/2.jpg",
     imgRes: "src/image/recommendation/responsive/rec2-r.jpg",
     name: "Chinese Opera Festival 2023: Opening Programme - Peking Opera Theatre of Beijing",
     date: "2023/06/16-18",
     location: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
     category: ["Music", "Family Entertainment"],
     free: "F",
     price: "380",
   },
   {
     image: "src/image/search-section/3.jpg",
     imgRes: "src/image/recommendation/responsive/rec3-r.jpg",
     name: "Chinese Opera Festival 2023: Opening Programme - Peking Opera Theatre of Beijing",
     date: "2023/06/16-18",
     location: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
     category: ["Music", "Family Entertainment"],
     price: "480",
   },
   // other shows ...
  ]);

  // Set ActiveIndex for showing choices
  const activeIndex = ref(0);
  const handleActiveIndex = (index) => {
    activeIndex.value = index;
  };

  return {
    modules: [Pagination, Navigation],
    activeIndex,
    labels,
    shows,
    handleActiveIndex,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const selected = ref('ALL')
const filteredList = computed(() => {
    return shows.value.filter((el) => selected.value === 'ALL' || el.category.includes(selected.value))
})
```

whenever you press the button, you only need to change `selected` ref.
`filteredList` computed will be executed whenever `selected` changes.

---

add this method in script setup.

```
const onClickChoice = (val) => {
    selected.value = val
}
```

and add @click like this.

```
<div class="choice-list">
  <div
    class="choice"
    v-for="(choice, index) in labels[activeIndex].choice"
    :key="index"
    @click="onClickChoice(choice)"
  >
    {{ choice }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean add the ref="selected" to button loop? We don't need to v-bind to update the value? Usually ref is for tell the order in v-for loop, it can only add ref & filteredList and make the filter function?

Comment: use `filteredList` in v-for

Comment: It does not work. Nothing happen when pressing the button. Is it missing the @click="" ? Also, it gives a warning that                                                             [Vue warn]: Missing ref owner context. ref cannot be used on hoisted vnodes. A vnode with ref must be created inside the render function.

Comment: you just should creating a method that changes the `selected` ref. I added the code, try it

Comment: This time no bug, but the filter function seem not work. It should get selected button value and use it for search.  Is it something wrong with the includes(selected)? Could you take a look for me? (I updated the current state and attach with code)

Answer (score -1):

Current Situation:

Added above code, but no reaction when pressing the row2 buttons.
[image]

[image]

Comment: please don't post code as images, it makes it hard to read and to use

Comment: I saw a lot of questions adding pictures in my time here. But this is the first time I see an answer doing it. To top it of, you link your code to a google drive file. This is madness.

Comment: is that work? `handleActiceChoice(choice), onClickChoice(choice)`. just remove `onClickChoice` and add `selected.value = choice` to handleActiceChoice method. 
and plz read this. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i updated my code.   
`- 374: (el) => selected.value === 'ALL' || el.category.includes(selected)`
`+ 374: (el) => selected.value === 'ALL' || el.category.includes(selected.value)`